# Parameterizing dom node in javascript

Tags: dom

To get child nodes of body, we have : document.body.childNodes

I want instead to call a function with a node as parameter 
ie. function list_childnodes(node) 
and get document.node.childNodes

how to do that ?

thanks

Comment: You're already passing in the node, just use `node.childNodes`

Comment: function call_node(node){
 console.log(node.childNodes);
}

call_node('head') or
call_node('body')                --- > get undefined

Comment: finally, i found the solution !

function call_node(node){
 s = document.querySelectorAll(node);
 console.log(s,s[0].childNodes);
}

call_node('head')
call_node('body')